# Script can not use and alert message "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again"

Tags: google-apps-script

my script can used until 28/06/12

project key : M3lNjCXkf28gSsG__pX-a2qKsRpcr8Sdm
SDC key : 497dba0bd1b73fc9

the user used this script by click the url in sites
(a href="/macros/sites?action=run&lib=497dba0bd1b73fc9&funcName=newQuotation")

When user clicked The Link in sites,It's return message "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again".

But,When I run Script in script editer,It,s can use completely.

How can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Please open an issue on the Issue Tracker